# What does '#type' mean in Haskell Foreign Function Interface?

Tags: c, haskell, types, ffi, preprocessor-directive

I have found this piece of code in the Haskell `sendfile` package:

http://patch-tag.com/r/mae/sendfile/snapshot/current/content/pretty/src/Network/Socket/SendFile/Linux.hsc

```
-- sendfile64 gives LFS support
foreign import ccall unsafe "sendfile64" c_sendfile
  :: Fd -> Fd -> Ptr (#type off64_t) -> (#type size_t) -> IO (#type ssize_t)
```

1) What does `#type` mean and 2) why do I get this error,

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Linux.Splice     ( splice.hs, splice.o )

splice.hs:40:12: parse error on input `type'
```

when I myself try to use it as follows?:

```
ghc --make splice.hs
```

splice.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

module Linux.Splice where

import Data.Word
import System.Posix.Types

-- SPLICE

 -- fcntl.h
 -- ssize_t splice(
 --   int          fd_in,
 --   loff_t*      off_in,
 --   int          fd_out,
 --   loff_t*      off_out,
 --   size_t       len,
 --   unsigned int flags
 -- );

foreign import ccall unsafe "fnctl.h splice" c_splice
  :: Fd
  -> Ptr (#type {- < parse error -} loff_t)
  -> Fd
  -> Ptr (#type loff_t)
  -> (#type size_t)
  -> Word
  -> IO (#type ssize_t)
```

(using GHC 7.4.x)

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/hsc2hs.html

Comment: I should point out that this foreign import should **not** be marked `unsafe`.  When a foreign function marked `unsafe` blocks, it can prevent other threads from running (in a program compiled with GHC with `-threaded`).

Comment: @JoeyAdams Oh thanks a lot for pointing that out! I am working on a polished implementation of piped splicing of network sockets for my proxy server. Which I hope to use on Linux instead of read / write loops I would still continue to use on other OSes for the time being.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by scdvvc, this uses the C preprocessing macros defined by [hsc2hs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/hsc2hs.html) to customize the code specifically to the system it's being compiled on.  You'd need to use `hsc2hs` to get the appropriate macros defined for your code.

Comment: The commenter on your original question, who frankly deserves more credit than I do.  ;)